# PHP not storing variable values between if

Tags: php

This code is for Telegram bot.
So I was trying to pass the value when user typed 'Category Check', which will return a news title and question asking if it's the correct category.
But after the user answered 'yes', for some reason the variables are reset so $title, $cat, and $check are blank.

How do I fix this?

```
function processMessage($message) {
  // process incoming message
  $message_id = $message['message_id'];
  $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
  $sender_id = $message['from']['id'];
  $sender_first_name = $message['from']['first_name'];
  $sender_last_name = $message['from']['last_name'];
  $message_date = $message['date'];

  if (isset($message['text'])) {
    // incoming text message
    $text = $message['text'];

//when user starts the bot
    if (strpos($text, "/start") === 0) {
      apiRequestJson("sendmessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Please select an option:', 'reply_markup' => array(
        'keyboard' => array(array('Category Check', 'Uncategorized')),
        'one_time_keyboard' => false,
        'resize_keyboard' => true)));

    }

    //category check that returns news title and category question to user
    else if ($text === "Category Check") {

      //MySQL Connection Details
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "user";
        $password = "pass";
        $dbname = "dbname";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `newsdata` WHERE `nb_count` OR `svm_count` <> 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $nb_business = $row["nb_business"];
        $nb_entertainment = $row["nb_entertainment"];
        $nb_health = $row["nb_health"];
        $nb_politics = $row["nb_politics"];
        $nb_science = $row["nb_science"];
        $nb_technology = $row["nb_technology"];
        $nb_world = $row["nb_world"];
        $svm_business = $row["svm_business"];
        $svm_entertainment = $row["svm_entertainment"];
        $svm_health = $row["svm_health"];
        $svm_politics = $row["svm_politics"];
        $svm_science = $row["svm_science"];
        $svm_technology = $row["svm_technology"];
        $svm_world = $row["svm_world"];
        $title=$row["title"];
        $nb_count=$row["nb_count"];
        $svm_count=$row["svm_count"];

        if($nb_business!=0)
        {$cat='BUSINESS'; $track=1;}
        else if ($nb_entertainment!=0)
        {$cat='ENTERTAINMENT'; $track=1;}
        else if ($nb_health!=0)
        {$cat='HEALTH'; $track=1;}
        else if ($nb_politics!=0)
        {$cat='POLITICS'; $track=1;}
        else if ($nb_science!=0)
        {$cat='SCIENCE'; $track=1;}
        else if ($nb_technology!=0)
        {$cat='TECHNOLOGY'; $track=1;}
        else if ($nb_world!=0)
        {$cat='WORLD'; $track=1;}

        else if ($svm_business!=0)
        {$cat='BUSINESS'; $track=0;}
        else if ($svm_entertainment!=0)
        {$cat='ENTERTAINMENT'; $track=0;}
        else if ($svm_health!=0)
        {$cat='HEALTH'; $track=0;}
        else if ($svm_politics!=0)
        {$cat='POLITICS'; $track=0;}
        else if ($svm_science!=0)
        {$cat='SCIENCE'; $track=0;}
        else if ($svm_technology!=0)
        {$cat='TECHNOLOGY'; $track=0;}
        else if ($svm_world!=0)
        {$cat='WORLD'; $track=0;}
          // output data of each row

//asking user if the category is correct
          apiRequestJson("sendmessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Is this news belongs to '.
          $cat.' category? '.
          $title.' '.$row["link"],
          'reply_markup' => array(
          'keyboard' => array(array('yes', 'no')),
          'one_time_keyboard' => false,
          'resize_keyboard' => true)));
    }
    //user answers
    if ($text == "yes" || $text == "no"){
          switch ($text) {
            case "yes":
                $nb_count=$nb_count--;
                $svm_count=$svm_count--;
                apiRequestJson("sendmessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => $cat.$track.$title."variable check")); //broken here, output: variable check

                break;
            case "no":
                //dothat; break;
          }
```

Comment: These are different function calls. When you do the "Category Check" you exit the function. Then you reenter with the function with `$text = 'yes'` (or `'no'`) but all local variables from the previous call are destroyed.

Comment: How can I prevent it to happen? I can't seem to get 'yes' or 'no' answer working if it's 'inside' the Category Check, but if I get it out I can't get the variables to stay.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible solutions to this problem that I can think of depending on how you are re-calling the function.

**USE STATIC OR GLOBAL VARIABLES**

If the session does not end before you call the function again you could use static variables inside the function or global variables to store the data. If you use the global variable solution then remember to define the variable as "global $your_variable_name" in the function.

**USE SESSION VARIABLES OR COOKIES**

If the session will end before function calls but will be called again by the same user then you could use session variables of browser cookies to store the data that you want to remain persistent.

**STORE THE PERSISTENT VALUES IN A DATABASE**

From the title of your question I think that you may need the values to be persistent between calls from multiple users. If this is the case then you will need to store the persistent values in a database such as mySQL.

Comment: I have tried global variable but for some reason it doesn't store the value. I can read the value of that global variable but not assign into it.

Comment: What I did:
1. Declare variables $cat, $track, $title outside and assign some values to it.
2. Declare global $cat, $track, $title inside the 'if'.
3. Assign each of those variables inside, then read it from the 'yes' 'no' if.
4. It returns the values I assigned earlier in step 1.